# Wp'ecommerce gallery thumbnail not working

Tags: javascript, e-commerce, wordpress

can you help with this, here is the link:

https://kidsdreamgym.com/products-page/cocoon-swings/cuddle-swing

as you can see, when you click the big image it will do the lightbox effect. However the thumbnails arent behaving like that. Please help me. thanks

Plugin use: Wp-ecommerce

Answer (score 0):

Just tried clicking the link, looks like it's throwing a fatal error at the moment:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '*' in /home/bmironov/public_html/kidsdreamgym.com/wp-content/themes/kdg/functions.php on line 14
```

If you click the big image and the lightbox works, but clicking the thumbnails does not do this and has never done this, there's a good chance it's either a bug or a feature request you'd have to make to the developer.

If I could see the actual markup, I would be able to give you some Javascript that could add the lightbox to the thumbnails.